# When is it okay to insert a page break before a new paragraph?

Tags: formatting, apa

I sometimes find myself with only one to three lines between the start of a paragraph and the end of a page when writing papers. When using the APA format, is it okay to insert a page break before the start of the paragraph?

Here are three examples:

**1. Heading is on the last line**

> [image: Heading on last line]

**2. Heading and two lines of text**

> [image: Heading and two lines of text]

**3. Two lines of text, no heading**

> [image: Two lines of text, no heading]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a heading, feel free to start it on a new page. Try to imagine headings as being similar to chapter markers, they mark the start of a new section of your piece, however, this is again dependent on your writing style and any criteria your examiners require.